# Tailwind scrollable component

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to build the page like this:
[what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzjIw.png)

There is a simple home page with navbar and splitted screen. What I want to achieve is to have no possibility to scroll this page as normally. I want to have possibility to scroll these two sites independently.
There is a list of components on left side and scrolling it works.
But on the right side, there is a single component that I want to scroll inside.
Here is the picture how it looks now, with my code:
[how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX8fQ.png)

And here is my `tailwind` and `react` code.

`App.tsx`

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <Navbar/>
            <HomePage/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`Home.tsx`

```
function HomePage() {
    return (
        <div className='flex bg-primary-grey h-screen'>
            <div className='w-1/2 h-full max-h-screen p-5 overflow-y-auto scrollbar-thin scrollbar-thumb-primary-blue'>
                <ul>
                    {
                        items.map((item) => {
                            return (
                                <Item item={item}/>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className='p-5 w-1/2 max-h-screen'>
                <RightComponent/>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

`RightComponent.tsx`

```
    function RightComponent() {
    
        return (
            <div className='bg-white rounded-md p-5 shadow overflow-y-auto'>
          
            <div className='rounded-md shadow text-center p-5 mt-10'>
                <p className='text-lg font-bold text-left mb-3'>Items</p>
                <ul className='flex mt-1'>
                    {
                        exampleItems.map((name) => {
                            return (
                                <ExampleItem name={name}/>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className='rounded-md shadow text-center p-5 mt-10'>
                <p className='text-lg font-bold text-left mb-3'>Description</p>
                <p className='text-left'>
                   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ultricies odio ex, at malesuada velit viverra vel. Aenean efficitur facilisis ipsum sit amet luctus. Aliquam egestas nunc diam, a efficitur eros sodales sit amet. Morbi volutpat vitae purus semper dapibus. Suspendisse tempus commodo risus. Duis eu lacus ipsum. Maecenas interdum quam in orci posuere dictum. Donec posuere nisi at vulputate fringilla.

Mauris laoreet suscipit ipsum non commodo. Nullam maximus nibh sapien, et cursus purus dapibus nec. Praesent consectetur tincidunt pulvinar. Duis pellentesque neque et sem aliquam, id sagittis ex pellentesque. Nulla suscipit tincidunt suscipit. Quisque leo nibh, lacinia sed purus et, finibus iaculis nulla. Phasellus eu maximus quam, et egestas lacus.
                </p>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

`Nav.tsx`

```
function Navbar() {
    return (
        <nav className='bg-primary-grey border-b border-secondary-grey'>
            <div className='max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4'>
                <div className='flex justify-between'>
  <div className='flex'>
                    <div>
                        <a href='#' className='flex items-center py-5 px-2'>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                 stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6 mr-1 text-primary-blue text-3xl">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                      d="M15.59 14.37a6 6 0 01-5.84 7.38v-4.8m5.84-2.58a14.98 14.98 0 006.16-12.12A14.98 14.98 0 009.631 8.41m5.96 5.96a14.926 14.926 0 01-5.841 2.58m-.119-8.54a6 6 0 00-7.381 5.84h4.8m2.581-5.84a14.927 14.927 0 00-2.58 5.84m2.699 2.7c-.103.021-.207.041-.311.06a15.09 15.09 0 01-2.448-2.448 14.9 14.9 0 01.06-.312m-2.24 2.39a4.493 4.493 0 00-1.757 4.306 4.493 4.493 0 004.306-1.758M16.5 9a1.5 1.5 0 11-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 013 0z"/>
                            </svg>
                            <span className='font-bold text-3xl text-blue'>App</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className='flex items-center justify-center'>
                    <form action="">
                        <div className='relative'>
                            <input type="text"
                                   className='bg-white rounded-full py-3 px-4 w-96 border border-secondary-grey
                                   hover:border-primary-blue
                                   focus:border-primary-blue
                                   focus:outline-0'
                                   placeholder='Keyword'/>

                            <span className='absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2'>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                 stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                      d="M21 21l-5.197-5.197m0 0A7.5 7.5 0 105.196 5.196a7.5 7.5 0 0010.607 10.607z"/>
                            </svg>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div className='flex items-center space-x-3'>
                        <a href='#' className='py-2 px-6 border border-solid border-primary-blue text-primary-blue rounded-full'>Publish</a>
                        <a href='#' className='bg-primary-blue py-2 px-6 border border-solid border-primary-blue text-white rounded-full'>Log in</a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

The main problem is that the `RightComponent` stretch under the page when I add more content. It should be stacked (in the middle of right page) with scrollable content inside

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can do this using `grid` and set for rows `50px and 1fr` or you have to set fixed height to `nav` for example `50px`

```
function Navbar() {
    return (
        <nav className='bg-primary-grey border-b border-secondary-grey h-[50px]'>
          ...
        </nav>
    )
}
```

and then

```
function HomePage() {
    return (
        <div className='flex bg-primary-grey h-[calc(100vh_-_50px)]'>
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks but it does not work :(

Comment: for me it works and looks like in the photo. Maybe be more precise about what you want to achieve.

Comment: `RightComponent` still stretches under the page when there is more content. It should be stacked in the middle of right panel. When I set for example `h-96`, it works as I want - with the scrollbar inside, but the card is too small.

Comment: can you add also that content to code?

Comment: ive just added. with this code it looks like in the second photo - there is too much content and RightComponent stretches outside the page what I do not want. I want to have this content scrollable inside RightComponent

Comment: add also variable exampleItems and function ExampleItem

Comment: id does not matter what content is inside. I have just deleted exampleItems and ExampleItem and left only  `p` tag with much text,  and it behaves the same.

Comment: I added tag p with height 1000px and works

Comment: maybe your tailwind didn't add class h-full to css.

Comment: well, that is strange. Could you show me the code inside sandbox or something like that? As I said, I tried with the text only and it still stretches outside the screen

Comment: Try add height:100%; in style.

Comment: the same result.

Comment: btw, are you coding with navbar or not? maybe that is the difference between our solutions

Comment: oh because you have nav.

Comment: no because you didn't attach it

Comment: well, thats inside `App` code I attached. But its ok, I could write the question better

Comment: Just attach function Navbar

Comment: check update. These are the simplest solutions.

Comment: thanks, I thought about the solution like that, but also had hope that it can be make better. Youre awesome and once again, thanks for ur time